# How to expand WPF frame to its parent width?

Tags: wpf, width, frame, parent

I try to define the width of a WPF `<Frame>` control to the size of its parant (`<StackPanel>` which fills the entire window width). For any reason the `Frame` element just takes the width of its child and not of its parent. I have googled for many "parent width" solutions (other container controls) but none of the worked with a `Frame`. Actually the `HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"` setting suppose to make it possible, but it doesn't work.

My code:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Background="BlueViolet" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
    <Frame Background="Yellow" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" />  
</StackPanel>
```

Any idea how to set the width of a `Frame` UI control to its parent?

**Update Answer:**

It seems that the width setting of a `Frame` does not to work in combination with a `StackPanel` as parent. When I use a `Grid` container instead, then the `Frame` width adjusts as expected to the cell width defined in the `Grid`.

Comment: Use a different Panel, e.g. a Grid or DockPanel.

Comment: @Clemens: I tried with DockPanel before, but got same result. I just figured out thet it's due to StackPanel. When I use Frame directly then it expands to the width of its parent which is a Grid cell now.

Comment: StackPanel is the wrong container for a child element that should expand in both directions. No idea what exactly you tried with a DockPanel, but you should replace the StackPanel with a Grid or DockPanel.